# Local domain name w/o DNS

Tags: windows, dns

Is it possible to make local web application (e.g bound to localhost:8080) avaliable via link like http://mysite without using DNS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. You can make it work, but only on your computer.

You can do this by editing your hosts file, add the desired domain name in there (can even have an extension if you want, such as example.com and give it 127.0.0.1 or your local IP address, depending on what your webserver uses.

This will only work on your local device though. If you want people to be able to use this, either they also edit their hostsfile, or you buy a domain.

I strongly advise against asking people to edit their hosts file. It is great for developing your site, but most people are inexperienced when it comes to editing their own hosts file.

One sidenote though... Technically speaking, using a hostsfile is still DNS, but you don't use a public DNS server.

DNS is the entire process of converting a name to IP address.